# Get / Retrieve Active Directory SamAccountName from a Group User with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, active-directory, ldap

I wrote a script to output all Users from an named AD-Group.

I can get the First and Last Name, but I need to be able to get the SamAccountName, too.

The many X´s are to fill fields that contain private information.

How do I get the sAMA?

```
Sub GetADUsers()
    Groupdn = "CN=X,OU=X,OU=X,DC=X,DC=X"
    Set group = GetObject("LDAP://" & Groupdn)

    'On Error Resume Next

    Dim Test As String
    Dim Test2 As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    i = 1
    y = 1

    Sheets("Tabelle1").UsedRange.Clear

    For Each MemberDN In group.member
        segments = MemberDN
        segments = Mid(segments, 3)
        segments = Replace(segments, "=", "")
        segments = Replace(segments, "\", "")
        segments = Replace(segments, "X", "")
        segments = Replace(segments, "X", "")
        segments = Replace(segments, "X", "") ' Im removing some "privat" things here
        segments = Replace(segments, "Y", "")
        segments = Replace(segments, "X", "")
        segments = Replace(segments, ",,", "")
        segments = Split(segments, ",")

        Test = segments(0)
        Test2 = segments(1)

        zahl1 = "A" & i
        zahl2 = "B" & y

        Range(zahl1) = Test
        i = i + 1

        Range(zahl2) = Test2
        y = y + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that using `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling is a very bad idea. This line just hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. Therefore you cannot find and fix any errors in your code. Remove that line, check if you get any errors and fix them properly.

Comment: i did that because of the split, some usernames are longer than the other. If i remove the "on error resume next" , my script will stop.

Comment: yes of course but you must fix that error. Hiding the message is no option it doesn't fix that error. It's like closing your eyes only. • The line even hides **all** error message which makes it even worse. The errors won't disappear just because you close your eyes.

Comment: i know that yes. 
So... it says me "runtime error 9 index out of defined range"

The problem is the "zahl2 = segments(1)"

You have some ideas for that?

Comment: You can easily get the upper limit of `segments` by `UBound(segments)` so a `If UBound(segments) >= 1 Then Test2 = segments(1)` will prevent the error because it checks if `segments(1)` exists before using it.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.
But still want to get the sAMA... You have some ideas for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the sAMAccountName by putting this inside the For Each loop:

```
Set objUser = GetObject ("LDAP://" & MemberDN)
sAMAccountName = objUser.GetEx("sAMAccountName")
```

p.s. I always like to clean up objhects that i have used when done, so at the end of the function i would add

```
Set group = Nothing
Set objUser = Nothing
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the help!
You saved my Project, that worked!

You seem to be pretty good in VBA?
You also know how to retrieve if an Account is disabled in the AD?